# Outputting the posts in a template is preventing tags below it to echo

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(
     array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)
);

if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
        $cats = get_the_category();
        if ($cats[0]->cat_name === 'Coaching') { ?>
            <div class="callout horizontal">

                <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>

                <div class="content">
                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>

            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The code above when removed allows this `<?php echo get_field('column_two'); ?>` code to run.

My question is simply why is the code above blocking the echoing of my `<?php echo get_field('column_two'); ?>`

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon `;` in the `<?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>` line.

Comment: Thanks that is true but hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Semicolons are automatically added with closing PHP tags.

Comment: Any other ideas guys? I'm out of them :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying get_field('column_two'); inside while loop, WordPress will look for custom field column_two inside posts, but it seems that this is present in page and not in post.

If you are trying to access get_field('column_two'); after while loop, you need to reset post data, wp_reset_postdata(); see here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

hope this is helpful.

Comment: Holy muffins... This has done the trick... Why this is needed is just ridiculous... Thanks for your anawer